# passing serializearray ajax data to laravel v7 controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an issue where passing a serializeArray data Ajax Post to a Controller ends up producing results that I did not expect.

The goal is after keying all the data in, then on submit, the data is passed to serializeArray(), then in each function becomes a proper array. Then it is sent via Ajax Post to controller.

Below is the code **example** not the whole thing, except the form. Continue after showing code...

**Form example before Ajax**(when i start using ajax, i delete the action)

```
<form id="form" action="{{ route('send.to.controller') }}">
 <input type="text" name="details">
 <input type="text" name="products[0][id]">
 <input type="text" name="products[0][qty]">
 <textarea name="products[0]serials"></textarea>
 <input type="text" name="products[1][id]">
 <input type="text" name="products[1][qty]">
 <textarea name="products[1]serials"></textarea>
 <input type="text" name="products[2][id]">
 <input type="text" name="products[2][qty]">
 <textarea name="products[2]serials"></textarea>
</form>
```

Current jquery i am trying to achieve

```
var x = $('#form-create-storing').serializeArray();

    var formData = {};
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
        if(field.value.trim() != ""){
            if(formData[field.name] != undefined){
                var val = formData[field.name];
                if(!Array.isArray(val)){
                     arr = [val];
                }
                arr.push(field.value.trim());
                formData[field.name] = arr;
            }else{
              formData[field.name] = field.value;
            }
        }
    });
     $.ajax({
      url: '{{ route("storings.store") }}',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'data': formData,
      }
     });
```

What i get from console.log

```
{userid: "1", grn_number: "111111", supplier_id: "2", delivery_order_name: "1111111111", delivery_order_date: "2020-11-18", …}
delivery_order_date: "2020-11-18"
delivery_order_name: "1111111111"
grn_number: "111111"
products[0][id]: "110"
products[0][qty]: "1"
products[0][serial]: "111; 
↵"
products[1][id]: "113"
products[1][qty]: "1"
products[2][id]: "114"
products[2][qty]: "1"
products[2][serial]: "111; 
↵"
supplier_id: "2"
userid: "1"
```

What is shown in Controller

```
array:1 [
  "data" => array:8 [
    "userid" => "1"
    "grn_number" => "111111"
    "supplier_id" => "2"
    "delivery_order_name" => "1111111111"
    "delivery_order_date" => "2020-11-18"
    "products[0" => array:3 [
      "id" => "110"
      "qty" => "1"
      "serial" => "111;"
    ]
    "products[1" => array:2 [
      "id" => "113"
      "qty" => "1"
    ]
    "products[2" => array:3 [
      "id" => "114"
      "qty" => "1"
      "serial" => "111;"
    ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see the above the products[#] has it "]" cut

Before i am using Jquery Ajax to send the data, i use the normal routing post form to pass the data,

How i want it to be is actually

```
array:1 [
  "data" => array:8 [
    "userid" => "1"
    "grn_number" => "111111"
    "supplier_id" => "2"
    "delivery_order_name" => "1111111111"
    "delivery_order_date" => "2020-11-18"
    "products" => array:3 [
      [0] => [
       "id" => "110"
       "qty" => "1"
       "serial" => "111;"
      ]
      [1] => [
       "id" => "113"
       "qty" => "1"
      ]
      [2] => [
       "id" => "114"
       "qty" => "1"
       "serial" => "111;"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Where do I go wrong?

**Update**

base on @miken32, i've change the following

> var x = $('#form-create-storing').serializeArray();

to

> var x = $('#form-create-storing').serialize();

> url: '{{ route("storings.store") }}',

to

> url: @json(route("storings.store")),

When it pass to controller I get

```
array:1 [
  "data" => "userid=1&grn_number=111111&supplier_id=3&delivery_order_name=1111111111&delivery_order_date=2020-11-20&products%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=110&products%5B0%5D%5Bqty%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5Bserial%5D=&products%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=112&products%5B1%5D%5Bqty%5D=2&products%5B1%5D%5Bserial%5D="
]
```

Comment: What you're sending is not JSON. I would suggest just `var formData = $('#form-create-storing').serialize()` is all you need to do. Also, do not include PHP values into JavaScript using `{{ }}`. Instead use `url: @json(route("storings.store"));`

Comment: Hi i update my post above, i get the data in controller like below

`array:1 [
  "data" => "userid=1&grn_number=111111&supplier_id=3&delivery_order_name=1111111111&delivery_order_date=2020-11-20&products%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=110&products%5B0%5D%5Bqty%5D=1&products%5B0%5D%5Bserial%5D=&products%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=112&products%5B1%5D%5Bqty%5D=2&products%5B1%5D%5Bserial%5D="
]`

Comment: Get rid of `dataType: json` and use `data: formData` in your ajax call.